# Kafka Streams with processing.guarantee set up to EXACTLY_ONCE issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working on a development environment with 3 (dockerized) kafka brokers on my system.
The brokers have transaction.state.log.replication.factor set up to 3.

In stream application config I set processing.guarantee as EXACTLY_ONCE and in consumer application config I set isolation.level as "read_committed".

I have checked other configurations on https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#processing-guarantee and I set up my environment according to the guide.

After a minute of message production from stream application that reads a state store and produces 100 message using context.forward(..) function, the consumer application stops reading, as if there wasn't any commited messages on the assigned partitions.

After some time the stream application crashes with the following error:

> "Aborting producer batches due to fatal error
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer
>   attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer
>   producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction
>   has been expired by the broker."

It seems like the stream producer cannot receive the ack and the transaction expires.

**Edit 1:**
When I stop the stream application, the consumer receives commited messages.

Comment: do you commit transaction anywhere? Show some code samples

Comment: Hard do say. I would recommend to check the broker and streams logs.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Rolintocour see my Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Advancing the Kafka server and client version seems to solve the problem

Comment: which version of Kafka server did you move to?